# How to divide the contour in three parts with the same arclength?

Tags: plotting, graphics, geometry

We set `MeshFunctions` to `"ArcLength"`,but it is missing the boundary point,so there only two points on the contour.

```
con=ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y] == 1/2, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {0 &, "ArcLength"}, Mesh -> 2, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[8], Red]]
```

[image]

Although we can `Cases` the point from the contour,but it seems not so elegant.

### Updated

It seems that `MeshShading` does not work in `ContourPlot`.

[image]

```
pts = Cases[Normal@con, Line[pts_] :> pts, -1];
ListPlot[pts, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Joined -> True, 
 MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}, Mesh -> 2, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[8], Red], 
 Epilog -> {Directive[AbsolutePointSize[8], Red], 
   Point@First@First@pts}, MeshShading -> ColorData[97] /@ Range[3]]
```

Comment: herbertfederer, can you share how you came up with the spec `{0 &, "ArcLength"}` ? (I   have never seen it before)

Comment: @kglr  In the early version, for example, 11.3, we only need to use`{"ArcLength"}`. but something have been change since such version. Now we have to use two `MeshFunction`, it maybe a feature or  maybe a bug.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### 1. Specify Mesh as a list

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y] == 1/2, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {0 &, ArcLength}, 
 Mesh -> {Subdivide @ 3}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize@Large]]
```

[image]

**Note:** Curiously, if we specify the setting for `Mesh` as a list of `{mesh, style}` pairs we can get rid of `0&` in `MeshFunctions`:

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y] == 1/2, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {ArcLength}, 
 Mesh -> 
  {Thread[{Subdivide@3, Directive[ Red, Opacity[1], PointSize @.03]}]}]
```

> same picture

#### 2. Use DisplayFunction to add the missing point

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y] == 1/2, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi},
 MeshFunctions -> {0 &, ArcLength},
 Mesh -> 2,
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize @ Large],
 DisplayFunction -> ReplaceAll[Point@x_ :> Point[Prepend[1]@x]]]
```

[image]

#### 3. Post-process to add the missing point

```
ReplaceAll[Point @ x_ :> Point[Prepend[1] @ x]]@
 ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y] == 1/2, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi},
  MeshFunctions -> {0 &, ArcLength},
  Mesh -> 2,
  MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize@Large]]
```

[image]

#### 4. Use MeshStyle to add the missing mesh point

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y] == 1/2, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {0 &, ArcLength}, 
 Mesh -> 2, 
 MeshStyle -> ({Red, PointSize @ Large, #, Point @ 1} &)]
```

[image]

### Update:

`MeshShading` is not an option for `ContourPlot`.

One way to get contours with multiple segments with different styles from `ContourPlot` is to extract the line coordinates and process them with a `*Plot` function that accepts `MeshShading` as an option (as done in the update in OP).

In the following, we wrap all `Mesh*` options (including `MeshShading`) in `meshOptions` and use `ParametricPlot` to process them to construct the desired graphics primitives and inject them in `ContourPlot` using a custom `DisplayFunction`:

```
ClearAll[meshOptions]

meshOptions[opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Module[{BSF = BSplineFunction[#]},
   First[Show[ParametricPlot[BSF@t, {t, 0, 1}, opts], 
     Graphics[{MeshStyle /. FilterRules[{opts}, MeshStyle], 
       Point[BSF /@ {0, 1}]}]]]] &

meshOptions /: ContourPlot[a__, meshOptions[o___], b___] :=
 ContourPlot[a, b,
  DisplayFunction -> 
   ReplaceAll[Line[x_] :> (Dynamic @ meshOptions[o] @ x)] @* Normal]
```

***Examples:***

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y] == 1/2, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi},
 meshOptions[
   MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"},
   Mesh -> {Subdivide @ 3},
   MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize[10]],
   MeshShading -> (ColorData[97] /@ Range[3])]]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot[{Cos[x] + Cos[y] == 1/2, Cos[x] + Cos[y] == 1, 
  Sin[x] + Cos[y] == 1/2}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi},
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
  meshOptions[
    MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"},
    Mesh -> {Subdivide @ 3},
    MeshStyle -> Directive[CurrentValue @ "Color", AbsolutePointSize[10]],
    MeshShading ->
      (Directive[CurrentValue @ "Color",  AbsoluteDashing[3 #]] & /@ Range[3])]]
```

[image]

Add the option `ContourStyle -> "Rainbow"` to get

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I just found out that `MeshShading` cannot be used in `ContourPlot`, it is curious to me. See my updated.

Comment: `MeshShading `is not an option for `ContourPlot`. Please see the update for a hack to smuggle `MeshShading` option into `ContourPlot`.

Comment: @kglr Helpful interesting answer! I tried to understand the option `MeshFunctions -> {0 &, ArcLength}`: I changed the first part `0&`  arbitrarilly to `3&`, but resulting plot doesn't change?

Comment: Ulrich, never seen this usage before.

Answer (score 7):

Using arrows and arrowheads.

```
pt = Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{0, 0}]}, 
   ImageSize -> 9];
con = Normal@
   ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y] == 1/2, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi},
    ContourStyle -> 
     Arrowheads[{0., {.1, Automatic, pt}, {.1, Automatic, pt}, {.1, 
        Automatic, pt}}]] /. Line -> Arrow
```

[image]

You can also use the following, whose "points" scale with the size of the graphics.

```
pt = Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}];
Arrowheads[{0.,
   {.012, Automatic, pt},
   {.012, Automatic, pt},
   {.012, Automatic, pt}}]
```